# How do I transfer changes from one branch to another?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm relatively new to GIT, and just made a rather critical error in the source control of my project.

I've been working on a change for immediate deployment, and just went to push it out to the Master Branch - we're on a relatively small team so the only other branch I'm using is for the release coming after this one.

When I went to push out my change, I realized that I was still on the branch for the *next* release.

I need to push these changes out to our Master branch, and I do not want them to be on this Next Release Branch.

Is there any way for me in GIT to move those changes on one branch to a different branch?

Alternatively, is there a way for me to safely pull these changes back from being Staged?

Comment: I posted an answer but as always: feel free to try to replicate the error (and the possible solution(s)) in a fresh git repo. A new git repo is really cheap to create and you should be able to mimic your problem in a few commits. Working with throwaway data should make you more comfortable to execute destructive commands like `git rebase` or `git push --force-with-lease`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To get the change included in master:

You could `git checkout master`, make sure your master is updated (`git pull` or `git fetch` and `git merge`), and then [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your commit from the "next release"-branch into master, and finally, `git push` master.

To revert the change from "next release"-branch:

`git checkout` the "next release"-branch, `git revert HEAD` to undo the last commit (or `git revert <hash>` if it's not the last commit), followed by `git push`.

Comment: Looking up the cherry-pick command, wouldn't I want to check out the Next_Release branch, then do "git cherry-pick master", rather than trying to cherry-pick while Master is checked out? Or am I misunderstanding, and would want to check out master and then "git cherry-pick next-release" ?

Comment: Never mind - I tried it myself and it worked the way you described it - I simply misunderstood the documentation.  Thank you!